# How can I ignore a property when serializing using the DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I am using .NET 3.5SP1 and `DataContractSerializer` to serialize a class.  In SP1, they changed the behavior so that you don't have to include `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes on the class and it will just serialize the entire thing.  This is the behavior I am using, but now I need to ignore one property from the serializer.  I know that one way to do this is to add the `DataContract` attribute to the class, and just put the `DataMember` attribute on all of the members that I want to include.  I have reasons, though, that this will not work for me.

So my question is, is there an attribute or something I can use to make the `DataContractSerializer` ignore a property?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You might be looking for [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx).

Comment: My domain layer didn't have the proper assembly reference, then I miss-read the documentation and ended up thinking it was a new feature of .NET 4.5. Tried to find back this thread to delete my comment without success (was in a hurry). Besides, looking at this answer's date should have ringed a bell.... 2009 .NET 4.5 post...) Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: On .NET 4.5 here:
System.Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMemberAttribute
works for any thing

Comment: Even 3rd-party libraries have added support for [IgnoreDataMember], like  JSON.NET.

Comment: Wouldn't a short example make this an answer actually worth of the votes?

Comment: This answer is incomplete and thus misleading. `[IgnoreDataMember]` would not work if the class has `[Serializable]` attribute. See details in the answer by [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792051/264097).

Comment: In a class annotated with `[DataContract]`, the data contract serializer (as well as other serializers supporting data contract annotations, such as JSON.NET) ignore unannotated properties by default, so `[IgnoreDataMember]` has no effect.

Answer (score 214):

Additionally, DataContractSerializer will serialize items marked as [Serializable] and will also serialize unmarked types in .NET 3.5 SP1 and later, to allow support for serializing anonymous types.

So, it depends on how you've decorated your class as to how to keep a member from serializing:

- If you used `[DataContract]`, then remove the `[DataMember]` for the property.
- If you used `[Serializable]`, then add `[NonSerialized]` in front of the *field* for the property.
- If you haven't decorated your class, then you should add `[IgnoreDataMember]` to the property.

Comment: what did you mean by "decorated your class" pls explain ?

Comment: If you haven't used any attributes on your class, like [DataContract] or [Serializable], then you would add [IgnoreDataMember] to the property you don't want to serialize.  See Paul's answer or https://www.checkoutall.com/Blog/Index/201410240204236271/ASP-NET-WEB-API-Part-6-controlling-members-serialization

Comment: This is much more informative than the accepted answer.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore that member and continue serializing the data structure/class?

Comment: How about excluding a PROPERTY when [Serializable] was used ?

Comment: [Serializable] doesn't serialize the properties, it serializes fields.  If you use auto-generated property (e.g. public string Property { get; set; }) then you won't be able to change its serialization.  You'll need to add a storage field to the property and add [NonSerialized] in front of that field.

Comment: @Daniel: For auto-generated properties, use `[field:NonSerialized]`.

Comment: @Doug: *"If you use auto-generated property (e.g. public string Property { get; set; }) then you won't be able to change its serialization."* That is incorrect, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/auto-prop-field-attrs

Answer (score 42):

In XML Serializing, you can use the [XmlIgnore] attribute (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute) to ignore a property when serializing a class.

This may be of use to you (Or it just may be of use to anyone who found this question when attempting to find out how to ignore a property when Serializing in XML, as I was).

Comment: Ah negative vote. Just thought I would post that because when I searched for how to ignore a property when serializing a class, this post came up. And I wanted to put it here if anyone found this post the same way I did.

Comment: [in meta] I think they voted negative because you should open another (more especific) question about XMLSerialization and answer it, so people would find that question more relevant in their search

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try marking the field with [NonSerialized()] attribute. This will tell the serializer to ignore the field.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not when using DataContractSerializer

Comment: He asked about properties not fields!

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is in conflict with what it says in the MSDN library at this location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

I don't see any mention of the SP1 feature you mention.

Comment: You can find the doc here (3rd paragraph, 2nd sentence): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: You're right about the link you posted though, I'm not sure why they don't mention it there, too.