# Calling WCF service from dynamics crm 2011 plugin

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, wcf-client

I have written a plugin for Dynamics CRM 2011 that calls a WCF service hosted on a different server. Below is the code in my plugin. In the class library for the plugin I have not used a service reference but used svcutil.exe to generate a WCF client.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IMyService";
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://test/MyService.svc");
ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpoint);
IMyService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
channel.InsertTest(testobject);
```

I am getting the following error:

'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Anyone had experience trying to do this? Or any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the WCF service in use elsewhere at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is with the serialization of the object you're sending.  Check to see if your testobject has a Task property.  If it does, consider ignoring it during serialization.  [See this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the service is set up correctly. I cried blood a few months ago doing that. Google for "Setting up a basic WCF web service for REST in VS 2010" and you'll probably get a hit on WordPress blog where I explain the approach. (Not trying to self-promote here. I wish someone else had that blog **before** I resolved the issue myself. Really.)
2. Show the code that you're using to connect to the service. When I get to work tomorrow, I can compare with mine and find any difference. I remember that I had this serialization issue but I'm not sure how we killed it. But we did, somehow. (And check if Daryl's hint works. It could.)