# How can I ignore a property with the DataContractSerializer (can't delete DataMember)?

Tags: c#

I have the following custom DataContract serializer:

```
public string Serialize(JobInfo info)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JobInfo)).WriteObject(writer, info);
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

But I don't want to serialize everything. I would like to create a custom attribure "DoNotSerializeAttribute".

If some property in `DataContract` contain that attribute then ignore it and do not serialize and if some property contains "password" in the name and do not contain this attribute then generate exception. How can I do this?

Comment: There is already an Attribute for this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer

Your question should be How do I ignore a property with the DataContractSerializer. For info on how to write an attribute see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Is this not what you're after? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx

Comment: @ojf Update question

Comment: @SimonHardy No, I cannot use it

Comment: Good question. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the DataMember attribute and keep your property like this :

```
public string Password { get; set; }
```

If your classe is decored with `[DataContract]` the `DataContractSerializer` will serialize all public properties decorated with `DataMember` attribute, and if your class is not decorated you can use `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.

**EDIT**

Maybe you can try with a custom surrogate I dont know if its the good way for doing this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = Serialize(new BackgroundJobInfo() { Password = "toto", Text = "text" });
        var myJob = Deserialize(s);
    }

    public static string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
    {
        MySurrogate mySurrogate = new MySurrogate();
        DataContractSerializer dataContractSerializer =
            new DataContractSerializer(
            typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
            null,
            64 * 1024,
            true,
            true,
            mySurrogate);

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(writer, info);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public static BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
    {
        var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo));
        using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(info, XmlNodeType.Document, new XmlParserContext(null, null, null, XmlSpace.None)))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = (BackgroundJobInfo)dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(xmlTextReader);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class MySurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        return typeof (BackgroundJobInfo);
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        var maskedMembers = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(
            m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true).Any()
            && m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotSerializeAttribute), true).Any());
        foreach (var member in maskedMembers)
        {
            member.SetValue(obj, null, null);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

internal class DoNotSerializeAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[DataContract]
public class BackgroundJobInfo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "password")]
    [DoNotSerializeAttribute]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need to create `MySurrogate` ? Maybe we can just 
`var propeties = info.GetType().GetProperties().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), true).Any()); ` ??

Comment: `MySurrogate` is used as a parameter for the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, what do you mean exactly ?