# ASP.Net Web API Xml searlization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are facing multiple issues with xml searilization of ASP.NET WebAPI. Currently we are using `xmlserializer` instead of `DataContractSearilizer` (which is a default serialization method for XML serialization) for two basic reasons.

1. In `DataContractSearlizer` We need to pass all the fields of object in ascending order otherwise getting null at api end.
2. We also need to pass namespace in XML header for passing XML object to web api.

For these two basic reasons we decided to go for `xmlserializer` instead of `DataContractSearlizer`. But now we are facing another issue which was not present in default `DataContractSearilization` mechanism. Let say we have an object like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    public int ID;

    [DataMember]
    public string CarName;

    [DataMember]
    public string CarType;

}
```

Now we were expecting that on client end we will only receive the those fields surrounded by DataMember attribute but unexpectedly we are getting all the fields whether DataMember attribute present or absent. This is perfectly working fine in json searlization and result was what we were initially expected. Can someone help us in this regard?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [IgnoreDataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) Attribute:

> When applied to the member of a type, specifies that the member is not
>   part of a data contract and is not serialized.

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int ID;

    [DataMember]
    public string CarName;

    [DataMember]
    public string CarType;

}
```

Comment: I think I have already tried this but it was also not working. Let me try one more time. Get back to you after few mins.

Comment: Oh, wait - try `[XmlIgnore]` since you are not using DataContractSerializer - I was to fast...

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Although my issue has been resolved now but do you have any idea that why in DataContractSearilizer we need to pass all the fields in ascending order otherwise getting null in field values?

Comment: No sorry, don't know about that issue. Curious.

Comment: @MuhammadKazim You didn't accept any of your answers right now. Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Sorry I dont know initially how to mark an answer as accepted. after read ur refer link i have marked your answer as accepted