# The same names of class attributes in JSON serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, json.net

I use `ContractResolver` in my code:

```
 public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    List<string> propertyList { get; set; }
    public ShouldSerializeContractResolver(List<string> propertyList)
    {
        this.propertyList = propertyList;
    }               
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
        {
            if (propertyList.Any())
                return propertyList.Contains(property.PropertyName);
            return true;
        };            
        return property;
    }
}
```

where `propertyList` is a list of required attributes for serialization

What if we have the same classes and attributes in data? For example :

```
public class Product
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ProductPrice subProductA { get; set; }
        public ProductDiscount subProductB { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProductPrice
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Amount amount { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProductDiscount
    {
        public int? SubId { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        public Amount amount { get; set; }
    }
    public class Amount
    {
        public int? amountId { get; set; }
        public string amountName { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value
    {
        public int? valueId { get; set; }
        public string valueName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to serialize `Product` class instance and serialize the `Product.ProductPrice.Amount.Value.valueId` attribute, but not the `Product.ProductDiscount.Amount.Value.valueId`

```
string myResponseBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = contractResolver });
        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(myResponseBody,
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    Encoding.UTF8);
```

Is it possible to do or not? How we can choose required JsonProperty? It is possible to compare DeclaredTypes, but it doesn't work for deep hierarchy.

Comment: Add the [JsonIgnore] attribute to the property you want to ignore

Comment: you answer might be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer

Comment: It means that serialization ingnore all instances of the class. But I need to ignore required instance.

Comment: Json.NET is a contract-based serializer so each type gets the same contract no matter where it is in the object graph.  Maybe you want something like [How to perform partial object serialization providing “paths” using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304128/3744182)?